# image name and dimension mismatched on fileselect through loop

Tags: javascript, html, css, file

As per my previously posted question below which i got answered. I need to get image name along with dimension.
I already tried lot of things to get them but the name and dimension is getting mismatched

[How to read(image data / dimension / filesize / name) multiple images on file select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45921124/how-to-read-multiple-images-on-file-select)

Comment: Duplicate of your own previous question, [How to read multiple images on file select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45921124/how-to-read-multiple-images-on-file-select) If you have anything new to add to that, please do it by editing the question.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below is the complete function to get image file information.

```
fileSelect.addEventListener("change", getSomeFile, false);

function getSomeFile(ev){
    var file= ev.target.files;
    if (file) {
        for(var i=0,f; f = file[i]; i++){
            if(!f.type.match('image.*')){continue;}
            (function(f){
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(file[i]);
            reader.onload = function () {
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function() {

                var span = document.createElement('span');
                span.innerHTML = ['<img id="thumb" src="', img.src,'"/>'].join('');
                document.getElementById('mid').appendChild(span, null);
                    var fileName =f.name;
                    var fileSize =Math.round(f.size/1024)+' KB';
                    var imageWidth = img.width;
                    var imageHeight = img.height;
            };
        img.src = reader.result;
       };
      })(file[i]);
    }
  }
fileSelect.value='';
}
```